# Compute text area given letter heights and a text

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell

I have solved the [designer pdf](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/designer-pdf-viewer/problem) question with haskell. The code works. I am posting the code here to know how I could have done it better.

> - First line contains the weight of each alphabet
> - Second line contains the word.
>
> Sample input
>
> ```
> 1 3 1 3 1 4 1 3 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 7
> zaba
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> 28
> ```
>
> Explanation
>   each character would take 1 space and multiply it with the max weight
>   4 characters * 1 space * 7 weight = 28
>   'z' has the max weight of 7.

Code

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

getintval::(Maybe Int) -> Int
getintval Nothing = 1
getintval (Just x) = x

solve'::[Char]->[(Char, Int)] -> Int
solve' ch lst = k $  map getintval $ map (\x -> finder' x) ch
  where
  k::[Int] -> Int
  k fb = (*) (length ch)   $ foldl (\acc x -> max acc x) 1 fb
  finder'::Char -> Maybe Int
  finder' g =  case i of
            Just(x1,x2) -> Just x2
            Nothing -> Just 1
            where i = find(\(val1, val2) -> val1 == g) lst


solve::[Char] -> [Char] -> Int
solve wght val = solve' val rec
  where
  rec::[(Char, Int)]
  rec = zipWith (\x y -> (x, y)) ['a'..'z'] word1
  word1::[Int]
  word1 = map(read::String->Int) $ words wght

main::IO()
main = do
  weight <- getLine
  pdfstr <- getLine
  putStr . show $ solve weight pdfstr
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have been hesitating to use a *block quote* for the problem description as it is not even close to a verbatim quote. At least for titling, revisit [How do I ask a Good Questio?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: A concern not really addressed by the nice answer from 
Gurkenglas: the initial [hackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/designer-pdf-viewer/problem) is quite explicitly about character __heights__ (as in the on-screen vertical dimension). However, your source code is about __weight__ which is confusing. For example, the first argument of `solve` could be called `heightsLine` or maybe `hLine` for brevity, not `weight` or`wght` . In a similar fashion, it is unusual to use `ch` (first argument of solve') for an input word. Normally ch would stand for a single CHaracter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getintval` is just `fromMaybe 1`. `finder` always produces `Just` - you probably meant to map `Nothing` to `Nothing`. `finder'` is just `lookup`. `foldl (\acc x -> max acc x) 1` is just `maximum` (so long as `ch` is never empty). `k` can be inlined.

```
solve' :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)] -> Int
solve' ch lst = (*length ch) $ maximum $ map (fromMaybe 1 . (`lookup` lst)) ch
```

`zipWith (\x y -> (x, y))` is just `zip`. `read`'s type can be deduced. `rec` and `word1` can be inlined.

```
solve :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Int
solve wght val = solve' val $ zip ['a'..'z'] $ map read $ words wght
```

`mapMaybe` throws away invalid characters. We can flatten the call tree by letting `main` assemble the pieces.

```
solve :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)] -> Int
solve ch lst = (*length ch) $ maximum $ mapMaybe (`lookup` lst) ch

parse :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]
parse = zip ['a'..'z'] . map read . words

main :: IO ()
main = do
  weight <- getLine
  pdfstr <- getLine
  print $ solve pdfstr $ parse weight
```